# RoR having trouble getting data from input into the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was trying to add a new column "company" to an existing model "order.rb" and everything seemed to have worked fine, but I cannot seem to get data from an input field into the new column in the database.

What did I miss?

Test Data in the database:

```
[1] pry(main)> Order.all
  Order Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders"
=> [#<Order token: nil, charge_transaction: nil, address_one: "777 Knoll Ln.", address_two: "P.O. Box 743", city: "Los Angeles", state: "CA", zip: "90015", country: "US", status: "SC", number: nil, user_id: "1", shipping: #<BigDecimal:69eed90,'0.595E3',9(36)>, tracking_number: nil, phone: "(626) 513-5035", expiration: "2015-04-03", created_at: "2015-02-06 20:07:04", updated_at: "2015-02-06 20:07:04", payment_option_id: nil, campaign_id: 1, full_name: "John Connor", quantity: 1, terms_of_service: true, order_uri: nil, tax: #<BigDecimal:69f3070,'0.0',9(36)>, company: nil>]
```

I can see that the company column is there (at the end), but no matter what I enter on the form I always get the value nil.

db/migrate/20150206193142_add_company_to_orders.rb

```
class AddCompanyToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :orders, :company, :string
  end
end
```

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
    def create

```
    @order = Order.new(
      :user => current_user,
      :campaign => @campaign,
      :quantity => params[:order][:quantity],
      :company => params[:order][:company],
      :full_name => params[:order][:full_name],
      :address_one => params[:order][:address_one],
      :address_two => params[:order][:address_two],
      :city => params[:order][:city],
      :state => params[:order][:state],
      :zip => params[:order][:zip],
      :phone => params[:order][:phone],
      :country => params[:order][:country],
      :terms_of_service => params[:order][:terms_of_service]
    )
```

app/views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
%= field_set_tag "Shipping Address", :id => "address" do %>

        <%= f.input :company, :label => "Company" %>
        <%= f.input :full_name, :label => "Full Name" %>
        <%= f.input :address_one, :label => "Street Address 1" %>
        <%= f.input :address_two, :label => "Street Address 2" %>
        <%= f.input :city %>
        <%= f.input :zip, :label => "ZIP or Postal Code", :input_html => { :class => "zip" } %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Based on your tags, is this a Rails 3 project? If so, check if the `Order` model has `attr_accessible` and, if so, you'll need to add `company` to the allowed fields.

Comment: I suggest you run Order.new(:company => "company name", :other_params...... ) to see if the problem lies within your model, controllers or on your form.  Then inspect your record, if your record saves in the console then your problem lies somewhere in your form.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you might want to use `current_user.orders.new(params[:order].merge(campaign: @campaign)` in your `OrdersController#create` method.

Comment: Thanks, to all of you for your suggestions they were helpful. It ended up being a combination of things including your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added :company in a separate migration but it appears that you forgot to add the `attr_accessible` for it in your model.

**If your app is running rails 3 add this to your Order.rb file:**

```
attr_accessible :company
```

---

**For rails 4 add the attribute to your order_controller.rb private method**

```
def order_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:company, :et_al)
end
```

---

***References:***

attr_accessor - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible